# Несрабатывание alert при оборачивании VK.Auth.login в функцию

Tags: vkontakte-api

Здравствуйте! Работаю с OpenAPI ВКонтакте. При авторизации таким образом:

```
VK.Auth.login(function(response) {
   if (response.session) {
        // Пользователь нажал на кнопку РАЗРЕШИТЬ
        alert('Вы нажали кнопку РАЗРЕШИТЬ')
   } 
   else {
        // Пользователь нажал кнопку Отмена в окне авторизации
        alert('вы нажали кнопку ОТМЕНА');
   }
});
```

alert срабатывает. Если же я оборачиваю этот код в функцию:

```
function au() {
   VK.Auth.login(function(response) {
       if (response.session) {
            // Пользователь нажал на кнопку РАЗРЕШИТЬ
            alert('Вы нажали кнопку РАЗРЕШИТЬ')
       } 
       else {
            // Пользователь нажал кнопку Отмена в окне авторизации
            alert('вы нажали кнопку ОТМЕНА');
       }
    });
}
```

то нет. И я не могу понять, почему. Прошу подсказать.

Comment: где происходит вызов функции?

Comment: `Если же я оборачиваю этот код в функцию:` ...но функцию нигде не вызываю... ? :)

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку <button onclick="au()">Авторизация</button>

Answer (score 0):

Стоило вынести кнопку за пределы `<form>` и заработало:

```
<form id="form" method="POST">
    <input id="in1" type="text" />
    <button id="btn" onclick="au()">сохранить поиск</button>
</form>

<button onclick="authh()">Авторизация</button>
```